# Is the Poisson distribution the only one where the mean and variance of the variate are equal?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

Or is this possible in another probability distribution?

Comment: Given any random variable $X$ with finite variance,  $Y=X+{\rm Var}(X)-{\rm E}X$ satisfies your requirement.

Comment: @Landscape Thanks, great answer.

Comment: You are welcome.

Comment: Another _named_ discrete example is the Flory distribution with pmf: $$f(x) = \frac{x-1}{2^x}$$  with domain of support $X = 2, 3, 4, ...$ . The mean and variance is 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Take a standard normal distribution $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$ and shift its mean by 1: $\mathcal{N}(1,1)$. This has a mean and variance of 1.

You can do this with any mean-square convergent distribution.

However, you might be asking because for the Poisson distribution, this is *always* true, regardless of its parameterization. In this case, I believe it is the only discrete distribution for which this property holds. To have such a property, you must have a one-parameter distribution, and there are only a handful such named distributions.

(Edit: As Robert Israel points out in the comments, it is certainly possible to construct such a distribution).

Plenty of other distributions have this property at certain values of their parameterizations (e.g. geometric distribution with $p=0.5$).

Comment: Only a handful?  Oh, you're talking about **named** distributions.

Comment: A nice family of discrete distributions with the property, supported on $\{0,1,2\}$, is $p_0 = 1 - t + t^2/2$, $p_1 = t - t^2$, $p_2 = t^2/2$, for $0 \le t \le 1$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Yes, sorry I didn't make that clear!